# UIWebView not loading data

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am trying to load a web page in a UIWebView on iOS 8.  The delegate methods - `webViewDidStartLoad` and `webViewDidFinishLoad` are getting called, but the page remains white.

The url I am trying to load is:

> http://us.rd.yahoo.com/finance/news/rss/story/
>   http://finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-test-australian-corporate-bond-035643114.html

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURLRequest *newsUrlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:self.newsArticleURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
    NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:newsUrlRequest queue:operationQueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil) {
            [self.newsWebView loadRequest:newsUrlRequest];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [self.pageLoadingSpinnger startAnimating];

}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [self.pageLoadingSpinnger stopAnimating];
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    UIAlertView *errorAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops" message:@"The page you requested could not be loaded.\nPlease go back and try again." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [errorAlertView show];
}
```

Comment: Why to use `NSOperationQueue`? You can directly do `[self.newsWebView loadRequest:newsUrlRequest];` after creating `NSURLRequest *newsUrlRequest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried following, this works perfect for me.

```
NSString *strURL = @"http://us.rd.yahoo.com/finance/news/rss/story/*http://finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-test-australian-corporate-bond-035643114.html";
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
[myWebView loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to load with error :%@",[error debugDescription]);
}
```

try this code to idenitify your error then you can solve it easily.